# Javascript/Jquery : if rel is found then append data, otherwise, don't append data

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/zD99p/

I've got the previous jsfiddle.  Right now, if you hover over "testing", you'll see a square block appear.  You'll notice in the html, the `<a>` for testing doesn't have a rel.  What do I add to prevent the appending on the text if there is no rel, but still append if a rel is found?

Code:

```
this.screenshotPreview = function(){            
        xOffset = 20;
        yOffset = 30;

    $("tr").hover(function(e){
         var text = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');   
        $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'>"+ text +"</p>");                                 
        $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - yOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + xOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#screenshot").remove();
    });    
    $("a.screenshot").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - yOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + xOffset) + "px");
    });            
};

// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    screenshotPreview();
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>content<a rel="Testing this out.  This could be a long description. Blah blah blah. Testing this out.  Testing this out.  This could be a long description. Blah blah blah. Testing this out.  " ></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a>Testing</a></td></tr>
    <table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the selector to only target elements with a `rel` attribute

```
$("tr:has(a[rel])").hover(function(e){ ...
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zD99p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for tr hover:

```
$("tr").hover(function(e){
    var text = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
    if ($.trim(text) === '') return;//exit if no text for append   
    $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'>"+ text +"</p>");                                 
    $("#screenshot")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - yOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + xOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");                        
},
function(){
    if (!this.t) return;
    this.title = this.t;    
    $("#screenshot").remove();
});
```

Comment: what makes this better/worse than what adeneo did or is it just another method of achieving the same end goal?

Comment: My code don't use complex jQuery selector `tr:has(a[rel])`, `tr` is more faster than `tr:has(a[rel])`(this will go throw Sizzle)

Comment: @Pinal - But the selector is only parsed once, and filters out the elements before the event handler is attached, while checking the attribute on every mouseenter happens every single time.